# Multiuser Authentication in laravel not work properly

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes, laravel-5.4, laravel-middleware

> ### I am Create to user login and admin login. User login for use default laravel Authentication and admin for i'm create guard. its work perfectly. no any proble to run my code just only one proble when i'm login as a user and after login login for admin then there also show user is login.

[image: Look At this Proble]
congig\auth.php

```
return [

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'admin-api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 15,
    ],
],

];
```

App\Exception\Handler.php

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException 
$exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    $guard=array_get($exception->guards(), 0);

    switch ($guard) {
        case 'admin':
            $login='admin.login';
            break;

        default:
            $login='login'; 
            break;
    }
    return redirect()->guest(route($login));
 }
```

Router

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){

Route::get('/login','Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')-
name('admin.login');
Route::post('/login','Auth\AdminLoginController@login')-
name('admin.login.submit');
Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's obvious you are using multiple guards to authenticate different types of users, so when you authenticate a `Simple` user through standard auth guard, and then you want to access routes that are available to users authenticated through admin guard aka `Admin` user, you need to authenticate yourself first, so there is nothing wrong with `Laravel multiguard authentication`, you are just implementing it wrong, I suggest you read up a bit more on guards and what means when you `authenticate` a user through certain guard and then trying to access routes that require a different guard.

Comment: yes.!! thanks but give me a just one help how to give condition here if im come form as a user the here admin guard execute and coming from user then this belove guard execute                                                                      {{ Auth::user()->name }}

Comment: `Auth::guard('<guard_name>')->user()`